# Make application that custom aspect ratio(regardless of the normal ratio)

Tags: android, aspect-ratio

I'm using Hikey970 board
https://www.96boards.org/product/hikey970

It has mipi to hdmi IC(adv7535) to connect HDMI display panel.
Display output is not normal(stretch vertically) because Hikey970 support only 1920x1080(maximum) resolution and our display panel only supporting 1920x1200.
(There are 120 pixels more then output)

I tried below two line in AndroidManifest as test but it alway convert to correct ratio.
android:resizeableActivity="false"


Even if the Hikey970 is sent to 1920x1080, the display(1920x1200) wants a normal screen(not stretched) to be output.

It is very difficult to change kernel side because of adv7535 mipi to hdmi converter. so I want resolve it in our android application side.(I don't care about android home screen and anything else.)

Can anyone suggest solution for this in app side?